# Processing file inclusion directives using mutual recursion

Tags: python, performance, recursion, regex, file

I am preprocessing a set of files where one file is included in another file with an include tag like shown below:

file A

```
include file B
include file C
 contents of file A
include file D
 contents of file A
```

Here I need to replace the `include` tags with contents of each of the respective files, just like what a compiler does. I have two functions for that:

```
def parseContent(self, rdbFilePath, content):
    finalContent = self.removeComments(content)
    includeFileSearch = re.compile(r'(?P<tag>(\s)*include+(\s*)\"(\s*)(?P<file>[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_/]*)\")')
    for includes in includeFileSearch.finditer(finalContent):
        finalContent = re.sub(includes.group('tag'),self.parseIncludes(rdbFilePath, includes.group('file')), finalContent)
    return finalContent

def parseIncludes(self, rdbFilePath, file):
    path = rdbFilePath + "/" + file
    f = open(path)
    pathDir = os.path.dirname(path)
    includedFileContent = self.parseContent(pathDir, f.read())
    return includedFileContent
```

As you can see, functions `parseContent` and `parseIncludes` call each other recursively to replace all the include tags in every file. The logic works fine. But it takes a bit long time to execute. Is there any better way to do the same with lesser execution time?

Comment: no it is not xml

Comment: What do you mean by slow? How big are your files?

Comment: Have you tried what this code does when the included file contains the text `$0.00 plus $1.23`? In other words, using `re.sub` looks wrong to me.

Comment: Is your file format line-based? In that case it might be easier to parse the input into a list of strings, instead of working with the `finalContent` (which by the way is not so final at all, since you are modifying it constantly).

Comment: @RolandIllig I see no advantage to working line by line.

Comment: @200_success in the code from the question, if there is a large including file that includes several other files, the whole content of that large file is processed again and again. By splitting the input into lines I wanted to avoid this needless copying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parseContent()` calls both `re.finditer()` and `re.sub()`, which is inefficient, because the `re.sub()` has to find the insertion point that `re.finditer()` had already found. What you want is just [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> *repl* can be a string or a function… If *repl* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of *pattern*. The function takes a single [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) argument, and returns the replacement string.

Going further, you should make just one substitution pass that handles both comments and includes. (You didn't show us the `removeComments()` code, so you'll have to adapt the regex yourself.)

The double-quotes in the regex have no special significance, and do not need to be escaped with backslashes. Also, the dot and the underscore characters do not need to be escaped within a character class.

```
DIRECTIVE_RE = re.compile(r'(?P<comment>#.*)|(?P<include>(\s)*include+(\s*)"(\s*)(?P<file>[a-zA-Z0-9._/]*)")')

def process_content(self, rdb_file_path, content):
    def directive_handler(match):
        if match.group('comment'):
            return ''
        elif match.group('include'):
            path = os.path.join(rdb_file_path, match.group('file'))
            with open(path) as f:
                return self.process_content(rdb_file_path, f.read())
    return DIRECTIVE_RE.sub(directive_handler, content)
```

`open()` should almost always be called using a `with` block to ensure that the filehandle gets closed automatically.

Note that I have used [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) as a portable alternative to `+ "/" +`.

Comment: @Hari furthermore, you are not doing anything with the captured optional whitespaces, so you can remove their parentheses.  `\w` is thr concise way to express `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and this may be used inside or outside of a character class.  In your case, you can use `[\w.]`. Out of curiosity, do you have input that contains `includeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee` that you want to match?

Comment: Errm... `[\w./]` (I overlooked the forward slash)